# Equivalence of a scalar to a vector:

Tags: linear-algebra

I just got myself into this position while studying matrix operation, I am sure others must have been there before . If A is a matrix of dimension (m,n) and k is a scalar then ( A + k ) gives the element wise addition of the scalar k to A.
So,   **A + k = A + K** **-----(1)**, 
where K is a matrix /vector of dimension (m,n) and have entries all equal to k.
Now can I say , from (1) that , scalar k = K , a vector of dimension (m,n)?

Comment: All of these operations look highly unusual. You cannot add (m,n) and (m,1), the dimensions don't match. Even if you want an element-wise addition of a "scalar", this would make the scalar eqivalent to (m,n) matrix, not (m,1). Also, "k" is not really a scalar in this case. Scalars scale vectors if applied to them; they are only defined in (n,n) case (automorphisms) and are equivalent to a multiple of a unit square matrix, not a matrix of all equal elements.

Comment: No. It's just a notation, and doesn't make a scalar be equal to a matrix. Btw, $K$ should be also an $m\times n$ matrix.

Comment: ok if K is equal to an  m×n matrix , then from (1) , K = k ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely not an equivalence, addition of a scalar and a matrix is not defined. Although it is not commonly used, you can surely say that if $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix and $k$ is a scalar then $A+k$ is a shorthand for $A+K$ where $K$  is the $m\times n$ matrix with all entries equal to $k$. But $k$ and $K$ are not the same thing, it is just notation.

A notation which is much more widely used is, if $A$ is a square matrix and $k$ a scalar, to write $A +k$ for $A+k I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix of the appropriate dimension. While more used, this is again notation, $k$ and $kI$ are not the same thing.

Comment: u cleared my doubt.Thanks...